# Style or performance: "new ContentValues()" VS "contentValues.clear()"

Tags: android, performance

I'm never sure, so I usually end up being inconsistent.

What is more efficient:

1. Re-creating `ContentValues` many times
2. Creating `ContentValues` once and then calling `clear()` every time before using it

Example **(1)**:

```
while (condition) {
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

  // Add to values

  // Create an operation
}

// Execute a batch of operations
```

Example **(2)**:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

while (condition) {
  values.clear();

  // Add to values

  // Create an operation
}

// Execute a batch of operations
```

Assuming large enough number of iterations to make a difference.

Comment: don't worry about efficiency at this point. I would go with creating a new object at each iteration, in case at some point you need to use that in a context where the ContentValues lives longer than the loop (e.g. if you put the objects in a Queue to be handled on another Thread.)

Answer (score 0):

Typical use case of ContentValues is like this:

```
// Defines an object to contain the new values to insert
ContentValues mNewValues = new ContentValues();

/*
* Sets the values of each column and inserts the word. The arguments to the "put"
* method are "column name" and "value"
*/
mNewValues.put(UserDictionary.Words.APP_ID, "example.user");
mNewValues.put(UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE, "en_US");
mNewValues.put(UserDictionary.Words.WORD, "insert");
mNewValues.put(UserDictionary.Words.FREQUENCY, "100");
```

Now, you how you use it for your requirements is upto you depending on what your logic requires from `hasMore()`

Answer (score 0):

I would go with values.clear() everytime. Now that I think about it, if the set of keys is fixed i.e. you put in values for the same set of keys in every iteration, you dont have to clear() it as well. You will be overwriting it for every iteration.